# Extract a url from a string

Tags: java, regex

I know this question is duplicated many time but I couldn't find the right answer.

If I have a string of urls such as:

"www.google.comwww.yahoo.comwww.ebay.com" (Assuming no spaces between links)

I want to extract each like individually and put them in array. I tried to use regex like:

```
    String[] sp= parts.split("\\www");
    System.out.println(parts[0]);
```

This didn't work! Any hint is appreciated

Comment: This is not generically possible, since that entire string is a technically valid domain name.

Comment: is `parts` an array? You are putting the split version of `parts` in an array called `sp`, yet you are printing out from `parts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Regex](http://regex101.com/r/jX0dY5)

```
(www\.((?!www\.).)*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/j4-5q1gYYCmNyQ5_)

---

### Description

Options: case insensitive

```
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(www\.((?!www\.).)*)»
    Match the characters “www” literally «www»
    Match the character “.” literally «\.»
    Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «((?!www\.).)*»
        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
        Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «*»
        Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!www\.)»
        Match the characters “www” literally «www»
        Match the character “.” literally «\.»
    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.»
```

---

### Java

```
try {
    String subjectString = "www.google.comwww.yahoo.comwww.ebay.com";
    String[] splitArray = subjectString.split("(?i)(www\\.((?!www\\.).)*)");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use basic string methods to break up the `comwww` into `com www` and then simply split on the spaces:

```
    String urlString = "www.google.comwww.yahoo.comwww.ebay.com";
    String[] urlArray = urlString.replaceAll(".comwww.", ".com www.").split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(urlArray)); // [www.google.com, www.yahoo.com, www.ebay.com]
```